# Weird behavior of GLSL code (variables, conditional operator)

Tags: opengl, glsl, conditional-operator

I was trying to implement a 360° texture into an OpenGL 3D project with an easy fragment shader, where I send a unit-vector from the position of the camera in the direction of each pixel, and by using some trigonometry I get the texture coordinates for the pixel. At first, everything was working fine, but in one direction (negative x) there were some pixels colored wrong (they had a color from the bottom of the texture, that they normally should not have). While trying to debug it, I found:

With this code, the pixel problem was there:

```
vec2 textureCoords = vec2(
        ((unitV.x < 0.0 ? 0.0 : 0.5) + (atan(unitV.z / unitV.x) / TWOPI)),
        (0.5 - (asin(unitV.y) / PI))
out_Color = texture(skyTexture, textureCoords);
```

But with this code it worked fine:

```
  if(unitV.x < 0.0)
        out_Color = texture(skyTexture, vec2(0.0 + (atan(unitV.z / unitV.x) / TWOPI), (0.5 - (asin(unitV.y) / PI))));
  else
        out_Color = texture(skyTexture, vec2(0.5 + (atan(unitV.z / unitV.x) / TWOPI), (0.5 - (asin(unitV.y) / PI))));
```

(vec3 unitV; is the normalized direction vector of the pixel from the camera position, it is calculated for each pixel as a local variable from uniforms.)

If I didn't overlook something pretty basic, these two versions should be the exact same, but the result is different...

Note: My main problem is not the fact that the pixels are sometimes wrong, its only the fact that these two, in my opinion exact bits of code lead to a different outcome consistently.

Comment: What is `unitV`? uniform? attribute? which range does it have? I ask because the second version requires `unitV.x` to be dynamically uniform.

Answer (score 0):

> If I didn't overlook something pretty basic, these two versions should be the exact same, but the result is different..

No, they won't necessarily produce the same results. They only will produce the same results if `uintV` is dynamically uniform.

When you sample a texture, the GL will calculate the texture coordinate gradients to determine whether the texture is minified or magnified, and when mip-mapping is used, also to calculate the level of detail to use.

Typically, the GPU will *approximate* derivatives by finite differencing with the value from the neighboring pixels in a 2x2 pixel block. So if you happen to have a 2x2 pixel block, where, say the left pixel has `uintV.x < 0`, and the right pixel has `uintV.x >= 0`, it will see a huge jump of 0.5 in the tex-coords, which means the GL will assume that half of the texture is mapped to a single pixel, needing a very high mipmap level.

When you write:

> ```
> if(unitV.x < 0.0)
>         out_Color = texture(skyTexture, vec2(0.0 + (atan(unitV.z / unitV.x) / TOWPI), (0.5 - (asin(unitV.y) / PI))));
>   else
>         out_Color = texture(skyTexture, vec2(0.5 + (atan(unitV.z / unitV.x) / TOWPI), (0.5 - (asin(unitV.y) / PI))));
> ```

the effect of the texture sampling is still undefined if `uintV` is not dynamically uniform, as @BDL mentioned in the comment. The issue here is that if you have two invocations in the same invocation group taking different branches, they will do the finite differencing against values which never are calculated becusue the neighbor pixel isn't even executing that branch. It might give you some "better" result, but only by chance.

The *correct* way to get this right with implicit gradients is this:

```
vec4 out_ColorA = texture(skyTexture, vec2(0.0 + ...));    
vec4 out_ColorB = texture(skyTexture, vec2(0.5 + ...));
out_Color = (unitV.x < 0.0) ? outCOlorA : out_ColorB;
```

However, in your use case, you might be better off with *explicit* gradients:

```
vec2 texcoords = vec2((atan(unitV.z / unitV.x) / TOWPI), (0.5 - (asin(unitV.y) / PI)));
vec2 gradX = dFdx(texcoords);
vec2 gradY = dFdy(texcoords);
out_Color = textureGrad(skyTexture, vec2(((unitV.x<0.0)?0.0:0.5)+texcoords.x,texcoords.y), gradX, gradY);
```